# Available fields in Facebook Graph API when POST'ing to feed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It's possible to both query (GET) or create (POST) a post on a users timeline/feed. But as far as I can see, [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) only lists the possible fields you get back when querying - not which of those fields it's possible to set when doing a `POST`.

Can anybody link to a complete list of fields that I can set during a `POST` to `https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `posts` connection on the [`User` object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). Required is only `message` or `link`.

Comment: Awesome! - But weird that there is a difference between the fields listed on the list that eSeptik referenced and the one you talk about. The list you reference also includes: actions, privacy and object_attachment. Where as the one eSeptik referenced also have a "source" attribute?? Both list the "caption" attribute, but it doesn't seem to do anything when posted.

Comment: ... just found that if I specify the "actions" field, the caption is suddenly used and the "picture" isn't cropped, but shown in its original dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

> As found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ under
>   Publishing section:

**Method:** /PROFILE_ID/feed

**Description:** Publish a new post on the given profile's feed/wall

**Arguments:** message, picture, link, name, caption, description, source, place, tags

example:

> - https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed/?access_token=HAGSX&message=Lorem%20Ipsum